# Restore a single document library from full backup?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, backup

Is there a way to restore a single document library and/or site from a full backup?
I need to restore a single file actually, but find that our vendor had set us up with only a full backup and an incremental backup strategy that backs up the entire farm.

Comment: What is the backup program that you are using? Did I miss this? Are you provided with one iso file?

Comment: We are using the standard backup/restore from Central Admin in SharePoint 2007.  We can also use stsadm commands, no problem there.

Comment: I would suggest try the Recycle bin if your document is available thier other wise do the full backup restoration

Comment: @Ashutosh Singh - The document is actually corrupt so its not deleted and waiting in the recycling bin, unfortunately.  Their site admin didn't turn on versioning either.  Is the only way to restore this single file by doing a complete restore?

Comment: unfortunately but yes :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i think you can restore your single file is to restore the full backup on some test server. The best practice to be followed while handling document is not taken care in your case hence that seems to be only solution

Comment: Well, since my document was corrupted, not deleted, I managed to do a full site collection restore and attach it to a new web app on my test server.  Such a hassle to do this every time a document gets corrupted!  Working with a 75GB database isn't easy - had to increase the HDD size on the test server, then the restore operation wouldn't "take" but finally managed to get it done.  Thank you.